# Rails: How to average multiple database entries after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, average

Rails 3.1

I'll simplify my application to get at my question.

I have two tables: Items and Reviews

Items has a column "Average_Rating" and Reviews has a column "Item_ID" and "Rating"

For each item, I'd like to store the average rating for its corresponding reviews. Although I can't figure it out, I feel like what I want to do is add something to the create and update methods in the Reviews Controller along the lines of:

```
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
@item = Item.find(@review.Item_ID)

reviews_to_sum = Reviews.find_by_item_id(@item.id)
@item.Average_Rating = reviews_to_sum.Rating.sum/reviews_to_sum.count
```

I recognize, however, that the above probably isn't close to correct... I'm a beginner and I'm stuck.

And I do want to store the Average_Rating in the database, as opposed to calculating it when I need it, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Where do you get column names like `Item_ID`? ActiveRecord prefers `item_id` by default and the method is the same. Capitalization in Ruby generally refers to constants.

Comment: Yeah, I capitalized them because I wasn't thinking when I originally built the database structure. I could migrate all of them to lowercase, but is the capitalization really a problem, or just non-standard?

Comment: It's just going to stand out as being irregular for now and into the future, so the sooner you can get around to standardizing, the better. You should always have a good reason for going against the grain. It also means you won't have to override the foreign key parameters in every relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  after_save do
    item.update_attributes average_rating: item.reviews.average(:rating)
  end
end
```

Comment: You're a genius. It never ceases to amaze me how clear rails code can be when you actually know what you're doing. I hope to someday actually know what I'm doing! Thanks again!